# Intellij connection to mysql database in docker problem

Tags: mysql, database, docker, intellij-idea, connection

Hello I have problem with connection. I wonder why it didn't work I would appreciate any help.

Database type is MYSQL which is located in docker container.

This is my inteli connection settings screenshot
[inteliJ connection settings with problem in screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5QRGl.png)

This is my application.properties file

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://192.168.99.100/registr
spring.datasource.username=root

spring.datasource.password=heslo

spring.datasource.schema=classpath*:db/structure.sql
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect = org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect

logging.level.org.hibernate.SQL=DEBUG
logging.level.org.hibernate.type=TRACE
```

This is my docker settings

[docker container](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ExF27.png)

[registr database grants](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RAinQ.png)

Telnet and ping images:

[ping command](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NY11F.png)

[Telnet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WMIig.png)

Comment: Does telnet work to this port/host?

Comment: I will add screenshots sec

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find a solution. Time for story.
Yesterday It was working on settings which I post in screenshots etc. Docker was showing  this --> docker is configured to use the default machine with IP 192.168.99.100
At end of day I turned off PC and today started and Docker changed to this --> docker is configured to use the default machine with IP 192.168.99.101

so I just changed IP and it's working

I appologize for my bad.